# Rails ActiveRecord: difference between after_update and after_touch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, rails-activerecord

I don't believe they are synonymous with each other, but similar in function.

1. Does `after_update` trigger even on a touch, or does it ignore only touches?
2. Does `after_touch` trigger for updates, or only for touches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[11] pry(main)> Foo.after_touch -> { Rails.logger.debug "after_touch called" }
=> [Foo(id: integer, name: string, age: date, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)]
[12] pry(main)> Foo.after_update -> { Rails.logger.debug "after_update called" }
=> [Foo(id: integer, name: string, age: date, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)]
[13] pry(main)> Foo.last.update name: "New name"
  Foo Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "foos".* FROM "foos" ORDER BY "foos"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  TRANSACTION (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  Foo Update (0.2ms)  UPDATE "foos" SET "name" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "foos"."id" = ?  [["name", "New name"], ["updated_at", "2022-08-10 21:10:37.296537"], ["id", 2]]
after_update called
  TRANSACTION (0.8ms)  commit transaction
=> true
[14] pry(main)> Foo.last.touch
  Foo Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "foos".* FROM "foos" ORDER BY "foos"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  TRANSACTION (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  Foo Update (0.2ms)  UPDATE "foos" SET "updated_at" = ? WHERE "foos"."id" = ?  [["updated_at", "2022-08-10 21:08:09.188057"], ["id", 2]]
after_touch called
  TRANSACTION (0.7ms)  commit transaction
=> true
```

Comment: Great concise answer. I know I technically didn't put this in the question, but it would be a bonus if you wanted to edit and append `save` and `save touch: false` outputs as well.